# How to locate elements on Java Swing Application for accessibility?

Tags: java, swing, accessibility, ui-automation, inspect

I'm trying to locate elements on my Java swing application window using Accessibility Insights for Windows. But, it is not identifying my own java swing windows application. However, it is working fine when I'm trying to locate elements on any other Windows App like, Calculator.

How do I inspect my own java swing application, just like any other Window App ?

Comment: Swing doesn't use "heavy weight" components or widgets.  The UI elements are all rendered directly to a single heavy weight canvas (ie the window)

Comment: FYI, [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) ([OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/)) is an alternative to Swing, with [accessibility enhanced as of Java  8u40](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/204).

Answer (score 3):

Java Swing application is not like other Windows apps. Swing uses its own GUI controls and engine which runs completely within Java. To Windows, a Swing application seems like a single canvas in the size of a window; in other words it does not use any Windows API for controls like buttons, labels etc. This is why you are not seeing anything.

If you want to make your Java program accessible, you should follow the *Java Accessibility Guide*:

- [for Java 16](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/access/java-accessibility-guide.pdf) (PDF, dated 2021-03, latest version)
- [for Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/access/java-accessibility-guide.pdf) (PDF, dated 2020-12, [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version)
- [for Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/access/index.html) ([LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version)
- [for Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/access/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then, after using this Java Accessibility Guide, would I able to inspect my application using inspect.exe or Accessibility Insights for Windows ? Would I able to automate its GUI testing by locating its elements directly from the script ?

Comment: No, you will still have to deal with Java accessibility completely within Java. You will need different tools.

Comment: Do you know what tools, as I have the same problem.